# Symfony2 REST bundle : Filter Parameter

Tags: api, rest, symfony

*How i do to get resource based on filter  parameter :*

As Example : **.../api/book?author=X**

If an complete example i will be happy !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), you can use [QueryParam](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Controller/Annotations/QueryParam.php) annotation and [ParamFetcher](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamFetcher.php) as follow,

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
// ...
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;

class BookController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     *
     * @QueryParam(name="author", description="the author of the book")
     */
    public function getBookAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
         $author = $paramFetcher->get('author'); // Can then be used to filter books on author

         // do something ...
    }
```

**requirements,**

- You've to enable the param fetcher listener by adding `param_fetcher_listener: true` in the bundle's configuration in your `app/config/config.yml` file.

Comment: i m looking to use it with  handler.. it's right ?
`public function getActualitesAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
    {
        $offset = $paramFetcher->get('offset');
        $offset = null == $offset ? 0 : $offset;
        $limit = $paramFetcher->get('limit');
        $ville = $paramFetcher->get('ville');

        return $this->container->get('genius_profile.actualite.handler')->all($limit, $offset,$ville);
    }`

Comment: handler part : `public function all($limit = 5, $offset = 0,$ville)
    {
        return $this->repository->findBy(array(), null, $limit, $offset,$ville);
    }`

Comment: Yep, the idea looks good as it helps you keep your controllers short and readable. You may also consider using the requirements and the default options of the QueryParam annotation.

Comment: i haved tryed my method with `public function all($limit = 5, $offset = 0,$ext)
    {
        return $this->repository->findBy(array(), null, $limit, $offset,$ext);
    }` but did not work :/

Comment: i got all the response without applaying $ext param fetch

Comment: Is there no out-of-the-box solution to automatically create filters for all entity fields?